# Querying a MySQL database using tkinter variables

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am trying to perform a query using the result form a tkinter option menu.

The defining of the Option menu is shown below:

```
EventToEditOptionMenu = tk.OptionMenu(EditEventsFrame,EditEvent,*EventList)
EventToEditOptionMenu.grid(row=2,column=2)
```

A typical example of what's contained in EditEvent is shown below:

```
('uytrds',)
```

I am unable to perform the SQL query successfully, yielding the error:

```
ValueError: Could not process parameters
```

Here is a screenshot of the table:

[image: event Table]

```
EventSQL=("SELECT eventname, startdate, enddate, starttime, endtime, cost, limits FROM events WHERE eventname=%s")
print(EditEvent.get())
mycursor.execute(EventSQL,EditEvent.get())
myresults=mycursor.fetchall()
print(myresults)
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a tuple back from `EditEvent.get()`? The docs indicate that `get()` returns a string.

Comment: @WillKeeling  It may be a string. When I do `Event.get()[4]` I get `t`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, I suspect the issue is that you're passing a string as the second argument to `mycursor.execute()`, rather than a tuple containing a string.

Try wrapping the result of `EditEvent.get()` in a tuple before passing it:
For example:

```
mycursor.execute(EventSQL, (EditEvent.get(), ))
```

Comment: This did not work :( I do believe that `EditEvent.get()` is a string, however when the SQL command is executed it returns no results, despite being give the correct `eventname`

Comment: OK so it sounds as though you're past the original problem of `could not process parameters` and now the SQL query is actually running, but just not matching anything. If you run the SQL query manually at the mysql command line with the value of `EditEvent`, does that produce any results?

Comment: Here is proof that the SQL syntax is correct. https://imgur.com/a/kbmTia7